# Windows PowerShell opens the vim editor with GUI. How can I disable it?

Tags: powershell, vim, command-prompt

I installed vim-console with chocolatey on Windows 11.

```
choco install vim-console
```

[image]

I didn't set environment variable C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe anywhere. But oddly, PowerShell is finding this path!

Furthermore, If I install vim in this path(C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe) with vim download website(https://www.vim.org/download.php), PowerShell opens gvim instead of vim-console!

In the Command Prompt, vim-console starts well.
[image]

[image]

Why does PowerShell execute vim with the GUI anyway?

Comment: It currently works. Maybe Windows 11 Update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To someone who got here: if you don't have choco installed then you should run powershell as administrator and paste this to install choco:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

taken from https://chocolatey.org/install#individual